# How to register both the Win32 and x64 version of an OCX control on single computer

Tags: activex, 32bit-64bit, regsvr32, win64

Just when I thought I understood Microsoft's confusing naming with regard to WIN32 and WIN64 registry and folders I read this article [(Using 32-bit or 64-bit ActiveX Components on x64 Windows)](http://cknotes.com/using-32-bit-or-64-bit-activex-components-on-x64-windows/) and find myself still a bit confused on how to properly register 32 bit and 64 bit OCX controls on the same WIN64 computer.  From the article it says that on a WIN64 system the default **regsvr32** is for registering 64 bit OCX controls and to register 32 bit versions of the OCX control I should use **C:\windows\syswow64\regsvr32.exe**.  The thing is I've been registering my WIN32 OCX control using the default **regsvr32.exe** (in C:\windows\system32) and it seems to have been working fine when I run my 32 bit app which uses the 32 bit OCX.  I have the following questions:

**Q1** How has registering WIN32 OCX with default regsvr32 been working given what I read in the article.

**Q2** I want to register both the WIN32 and WIN64 versions of the OCX control on a single computer.  From the article it seems like I should use the two different versions of regsvr32.exe from syswow64 and system32 for WIN32 and WIN64 versions respectively.  Is this correct?

**Q3** Can the GUID for the OCX be the same for both the WIN32 and WIN64 versions?  I'm thinking it can be the same since a different portion of the registry is used to register for each of these architectures.  Correct?

**Q4** Where do I look in the registry to confirm that both 64 and 32 bit versions of the OCX have been registered to confirm that registering the 2nd one didn't overwrite the first one?

Comment: A1 & A2 Well since no one has replied to this I'll add what I've learned since posting.  It seems the article I referenced is misleading in describing how to run 32 and 64 bit regsvr32.exe.  From my own testing it seems that the default 64 bit regsvr32.exe can be used to register both 32bit and 64bit OCX controls.  It seems regsvr32 (the 64 bit version at least) looks at the target OCX or DLL file and determines if it is 32 or 64 bit and installs it in the appropriate registry.  There doesn't seem to be any need to use the 32 bit version of regsvr32 on 64bit windows.

Comment: A3 Yes both 64 and 32 bit versions can be registered which use the same GUID.

Comment: A4 For 32bit OCX in
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID  
 area of the registry and for 64 bit its in  
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID

Comment: You can answer your own question. Then marking is as answered might help others on this site. I almost disregarded looking at your question for help, as there was no answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per suggestion in comment by Andrew here is my comments as an answer.

A1 & A2 Well since no one has replied to this I'll add what I've learned since posting. It seems the article I referenced is misleading in describing how to run 32 and 64 bit regsvr32.exe. From my own testing it seems that the default 64 bit regsvr32.exe can be used to register both 32bit and 64bit OCX controls. It seems regsvr32 (the 64 bit version at least) looks at the target OCX or DLL file and determines if it is 32 or 64 bit and installs it in the appropriate registry. There doesn't seem to be any need to use the 32 bit version of regsvr32 on 64bit windows.

A3 Yes both 64 and 32 bit versions can be registered which use the same GUID.

A4 For 32bit OCX in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID area of the registry and for 64 bit its in 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID